# Dynamic Router Path validation in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

{path: '/institute_details/:id', component: require('./views/institutedetails/instdetails.vue')},

I want to validate id before redirect on path

```js
{path: '/institute_details/:id', component: require('./views/institutedetails/instdetails.vue')},



methods: {   
      validateData() {
        var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$")
        var string1=this.seatno
        var vm=this
        if(this.seatno==' ' || this.seatno.length==0 ){
          this.seatno=''
          alert("Enter Your Seat Number...!")
          this.$refs.seatno1.focus();
        }else if(!re.test(string1)){
          this.seatno=''
          alert("Invalid...!")
          this.$router.push({path:'/' })
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="btn_result">
  <span v-on:click="validateData">
    <router-link :to="'institute_details/' + seatno " class="btn btn-success">View Path
    </router-link>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beforeRouteEnter` hook in your component.

And its usage is specified in the official vue-router document.[see vue-router document](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

**Code Example in your component**

```
export default {
    data() {
        // define your component's data here.
    },

    methods: {
        validateDate() {
            // function to valiate your data
        },
    },

    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        // check before enter the route
        // if check failed, you can cancel this routing

        // fake code here
        const isCheckPassed = checkWithSomeLogic();

        if (isCheckPassed) {
            next();
        } else {

            // cancel this routing
            // or redirect to the page you want with next function
            next({
                path: 'route you want to redirect to',
                query: {
                    // your query params here
                },
            });
        }
    },
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi im using  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        
        axios.get(eventBus.apiURL+'result/' +this.seatno)
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log('RES' + response.data.scc_number)
              
            }).catch(error => {
              alert('Invalid')
           
          })
    }, bt it shows error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'seatno' of undefined

Comment: component's data is not accessable in beforeRouteEnter hook. 

As specified in official document:
`beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
    // does NOT have access to 'this' component instance,
    // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
  },`

Comment: [beforeRouteEnter document](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: Or if you just want check data before routing.
Just replace router-link element with Programmatic Navigation in your validateData function.
In your validateData function, if validate passed, route to the path you want.If not, do nothing or give a tip to the user(for example).
[Programmatic Navigation Document](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html).

Comment: i have multiple routes on same page and i m using beforeRouteEnter for validation but it apply for all routes. I want to validate it for single route

Comment: Can i set to parameter for a particular route...if yes then how?

Comment: Each route has its own name or path.You can refer to each route's information by function beforeRouteEnter's parameter - from(it's a [Route Object](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html)).And then you can apply different validation methods for different routes.
like
`switch(from.name) {
 case 'routeName1':
  // do something for route1
  break;
 case 'routeName2':
  // do something for route2
  break;
 default:
  // noop
}
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch only to particular route and apply logic on that add condition in statement `if(to.fullPath.includes('/yoururl'))` then `next()`